# Read PhantomJS output with php

Tags: php, phantomjs

I'm trying to read some output in PhantomJS with PHP, but I didn't find the trick how to deal with it. Anyone did it before? Are there some solutions?

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http....', function(status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to access network');
    } else {
         page.evaluate(function() {
            var list = document.querySelectorAll('div.resume');
            for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
               console.log((i + 1) + ":" + list[i].innerText);
            }
         });
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

and in php

```
$result = shell_exec($cmd...);
print($result);
```

Comment: Do you see output when you run the phantomjs command in a shell? The script as seen here shouldn't produce any output.

Comment: yes when i run it only with phantomjs, i mean the output from console.log